# Sync Fox-pro database with MS-SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, synchronization, foxpro

I have an application running on Fox-pro database. Have added a module to the same application that runs on MS-SQL database. I need to sync both the database in real-time at different intervals. I will eventually move the application to use MS-SQL, but till the code is changed, I need to sync the databases.

Any script or tool is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have not used this product, but you could look at DBSync for FoxPro https://dbconvert.com/foxpro/mssql/

Comment: I have already used it...and also bought the paid version.. Its useless..DO NOT USE the above product.
@Frank, thanks for the efforts though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a tool, and it is really working absolutely fine.
The link to tool is : [Data Loader](http://www.dbload.com/).

Thanks to all for giving your time and efforts

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any magic bullet for this - anyone who has done it will have had a particular requirement and have coded it themselves I would guess.